# How do I find a JSON value with a specific ID?

Tags: javascript

I have an object and I’m trying to find a specific value using an ID in ECMAScript6.

I’ve tried something like this: `myvalue = this.json.find(x => x == '1234');`

The JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "abcde1234": {
        "value": 4
      }
    },
    {
      "zxcv4567": {
        "value": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

All the examples I’ve found can only find off named key-value pairs.

Comment: Hi Kyle, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to add the JSON you are working with (i.e. create a [mre]). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry my bad! This is what the json actually looks like. So basically I'm trying to find 'abcde1234' and get the value. Tried a lot of things and none seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
json.results.find(x => /1234/.test(Object.keys(x)[0]));
```

```js
json = {
    "results": [
      {
        "abcde1234": {
          "value": 4
        }
      },
      {
        "zxcv4567": {
          "value": 2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  

let r = json.results.find(x => /1234/.test(Object.keys(x)[0]));

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Question, how do you pass a parameter in place of 1234 in the test function?

Comment: if you want to pass dynamic parameter then you need to use `var param="1234"; var re = new RegExp(param)` and instead `/1234/.test(...` use `re.test(...`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const json = {
  '1234': { 'value' : 4},
  '5678': { 'value' : 10}
};

const value = json['1234'];
console.log(value);
```

The JSON data doesn't seem proper.
But in case you are finding by key, you can directly access this, something like:

Comment: Maybe not proper, but your code snippet actually works.

Comment: Yeah the above works but when I migrate it to my code it doesn't even though the structure seems the same. But getting in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Parsed JSON maps directly to JavaScript types: Object, Array, boolean, string, number, null. Your example used `find()` which is (normally) a method used with arrays. If your JSON was structured like this, you could expect to use find:

```
const jsonString = '["a", "b", "c"]';
const jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
jsonData.find(x => x === "a"); // "a"
```

But it seems like your data is structured as an object, so you can use normal property access:

```
const jsonString = '{"1234": {"value": 4}, "5678": {"value": 10}}';
const jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

jsonData["1234"]       // {value: 4}
jsonData["1234"].value // 4
```

EDIT

OP changed the data example, so the above code is less directly applicable, but the general point is: once you parse it, **it's just javascript**.